# Web service for sharing photo/videos from an event for a private group

Tags: file-sharing, photos, privacy-protection

Following a hell of a weekend at a private live roleplay, we're looking to share the photos and video.  Several present either have not yet given permission to share, or expressly don't want their photos shared outside the group present at the event.  At the same time, we all want to see and share the photos we took of each other.

So I'd ideally like a dropbox-style service, with the following properties:

1) Strong privacy protection from unauthorised download.  At a minimum, access restricted to members of the group, either using a common username/password login, or better, explicitly authorised to members of the group by a moderator.

2) Very cheap or, ideally, free capacity sufficient to upload photos and video taken by a couple of dozen people over a busy weekend.

3) Tagging possible but avoidable.  Several people explicitly want not to be tagged in photos.

4) No automatic links / crawling from social media. Nothing should turn up on Google searches and the like.

5) Data should be genuinely-deletable when we're done.

6) ToS should be consistent with this, and site should not have a history of changing it in Bad Ways.  (This is what lets Dropbox out.)

7) Easy to use for the many non-technical users.  (It's OK for it to be fiddly to set up initially.)

Alternatives along completely different lines also welcome as long as they accomplish the objective.

Answer (score 1):

Flickr supports most of these features if you set it up properly. See the following link for more details:

http://www.flickr.com/help/privacy/

You can create a special Flickr account for this group, and then invite only those members as friends / family to view the event photos.